# go routine getting blocked

Tags: go, goroutine

I am leaning go, so this might be a stupid question.

I can't seem to figure out why one of my go routines is being blocked by another.  My understanding (could be wrong) go routines run as independent light weight threads so they should not be blocking each other, unless I have messed up :)

I have pasted the code below and would appreciate any help / tips to figure this out.

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "time"
import "sync"



func worker( jobs <-chan int, job2 chan<- int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for j := range jobs {
        fmt.Println("finished job", j)
        time.Sleep(time.Second/2)

        if(j%3==0){
           job2 <- j   
        }  

   } 
   close(job2)
   fmt.Println("channel job2 closed")
 }

func worker2(job2 <-chan int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i:= range job2 {
        fmt.Println(i)
        time.Sleep(time.Second*10)
    } 
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {

    wg.Add(2)
    jobs := make(chan int)

    job2 := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        for j := 1; j <= 10; j++ {
             jobs <- j
        }
        close(jobs)
        fmt.Println("channel jobs closed")
    }()

    go worker(jobs,job2)
    go worker2(job2)

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("exiting main")     

}
```

I get the following output when I run this code

```
finished job 1
finished job 2
finished job 3
finished job 4
3
finished job 5
finished job 6
6
finished job 7
finished job 8
finished job 9
9
finished job 10
channel jobs closed
channel job2 closed
exiting main
```

however I was expecting something like this?

```
finished job 1
finished job 2
finished job 3
finished job 4
3
finished job 5
finished job 6
finished job 7
finished job 8
finished job 9
finished job 10
channel jobs closed
6
9    
channel job2 closed
exiting main
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your routines are sort-of blocking because the channels aren't buffered. A write/read on an unbuffered channel is a blocking operation. Therefore your routines by definition have to wait on eachother.

Essentially, your sleep of half a second is kind of irrelevant, because the second worker sleeps for 10 seconds. Those 10 seconds will block reads/writes to the second channel. Add a buffer to the channel to get around this.

Some other things I'd like to point out are:

- `time.Sleep(time.Second/2)` isn't going to work (well, it is, but dividing by 3 for example isn't). `time.Sleep` expects a `time.Duration` argument, which is an `int64`. You need to pass something like `time.Millisecond * 500` instead
- It's bad form to pass a channel to a routine, and close it from the routine that didn't create the channel. The channels creation and closing should be contained within a single routine. If not, it works, but maintenance becomes a real nightmare.
- Group your imports, instead of repeating the `import "package"`, just use `import ( "package1"\n"package2")`
- Don't use globals if you don't have to. Create the waitgroup in the function that starts all of the routines, and pass a pointer to it to all routines. Including the anonymous function, just to be safe (once you start adding buffers to channels, for example)
- Consider looking into `context.Context` and the `select` construct. You can create a `context.WithCancel` and in select listen for `ctx.Done()` in all routines. Then you can just cancel all routines in one go without having to handle signals and pushing stuff onto a cancel channel

### Demo

I've changed a couple of things (mainly channel creation, and some minor code-cleanup), and created a playground example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/nOjA0vvW2qM)

Comment: thanks for your reply Elias, please correct me if I am wrong but the buffered channel would also block once the buffer is filled up? 

I was trying to come up with a solution that would not block at all because the application that I am writing I dont know what the appropriate buffer should be, to make sure it remains unblocked.

thanks for the tip on time.Seconds

re the last point, I was struggling with deadlocks if I dont close the channel where I am closing now. Could you suggest an alternative whereby the channel is closed in the same routine?

Comment: @prog_noob: Yes, but considering you know how much data you're pushing onto the main channel, that shouldn't be an issue. Blocking channels once the buffer fills up is completely fine, mainly because it's a mechanism that easily allows you to throttle the throughput. Sometimes having a buffer of just 1 is all it takes (e.g. when writing a package that handles signals but you don't want it to interfere with the code using that package).

Comment: thanks, I've had a little play I think I might be able change the code by buffering the second channel. I have also noticed the additional tips in your original comment I will check them out.

Comment: @prog_noob linked to a playground example where I just pasted your code and changed a couple of things. I've added some more details in the `fmt` output so it's clear where values are being consumed, but the overal idea should come through

Comment: @prog_noob: Updated the playground link. channels are, essentially like shared slices with a `cap` (being the buffer). You can dynamically determine the size of the buffer of the second channel: we're forwarding multiples of 3, so `cap(jobs)/3` might be a good buffer size